# ①「the OP's issueとは、何ですか?」本家さんに投稿したら、困った。②「私は何をしたらいいですか？」

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, 英語

先によろしくお願いします。

(参考)Polynomial (4)*x**3+(2*a)*x**2+(b-3)*x+(-a) ==> 4*x**3+2*a*x**2+(b-3)*x-a ?howto
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797546/polynomial-4x32ax2b-3x-a-4x32ax2b-3x-a-howto
「SO」は、「Stack Overflow」だと思います。

(google翻訳より)
これを編集して、これが良い答えである理由を説明すると役に立ちます。

(google翻訳より)
このコードはOPの問題を解決する可能性がありますが、コードがOPの問題にどのように対処するかについての説明を含めることをお勧めします。
このようにして、将来の訪問者はあなたの投稿から学び、それを自分のコードに適用することができます。 SOはコーディングサービスではなく、
知識のリソースです。また、質の高い、完全な回答が支持される可能性が高くなります。これらの機能は、
すべての投稿が自己完結型であるという要件とともに、フォーラムとは異なるプラットフォームとしてのSOの強みの一部です。
編集して追加情報を追加したり、ソースドキュメントで説明を補足したりできます。 –

(私の理解)
SOはコーディングサービスではない。
ごめんなさい。

Comment: 翻訳を載せるよりも、日本語であなたの困りごとを説明したほうが伝わりやすいと思います。いま現在のタイトルや本文だと、翻訳でない部分も片言の日本語に見えます。

Comment: こちらのご質問についてこの「スタック・オーバーフロー メタ」で扱える内容のご質問なのか[別の投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3327/19110)にて討議した結果、ひとまずは扱いにくいという結論になったので一度こちらのご質問をクローズ状態にいたしました。ご了承くださいませ。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

まず大前提として、 https://stackoverflow.com は英語版サイトであり、英語版サイトに対応するメタサイトは https://meta.stackoverflow.com です。英語版 Stack Overflow で困ったことがあれば、英語版 Stack Overflow Meta に投稿いただきたかったです。今回の場合ですとそのままコメントで "What is OP?" などと聞いても良かったでしょう。

今ご覧になっているこのサイト https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com は日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー https://ja.stackoverflow.com のメタサイトであり、基本的には日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでの困りごとを解決するためのサイトです。英語版 Stack Overflow とは文化が違うところもあるので、英語版での困りごとは扱っていないという認識です。

一方、とはいえ単にクローズしてしまうのは日本語を使うプログラマーにとって便利なサイトを作っていくためにはならない気がしました。このため今回はここに回答を投稿しつつ、このメタ質問自体はクローズ対象ではないか、と発案しておきます。

### 質問に対する答え

SO は Stack Overflow の略、OP は「元々の質問者」を示す Original Poster の略です。このような専門用語はこちらに意味がまとまっています：[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/341401)。英語で使われる略語が大半なので今のところ日本語訳はありません。

また、質問文にも書かれている[こちらのコメント](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797546/polynomial-4x32ax2b-3x-a-4x32ax2b-3x-a-howto#comment109328122_61800322)について、これは大雑把に言えば「確かにこの回答を信じてコピペすれば今回に限れば解決できるかもしれないけど、なんでこれで解決できるのか全く説明が無いから質問者さんの次には繋がっていなそうだし、もし同じことで困った人がこの質問を見に来ても全然学べることが無いよ。だから説明を書いてね」という趣旨です。Stack Overflow はナレッジを蓄積していくためのサービスであり、場当たり的な回答を残しておいても「蓄積」にはなりません（これは日本語版スタック・オーバーフローも同じです）。このため回答には how だけではなく why も書くことを推奨しています。