# 英語版 Stack Overflow の分からないことを日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー メタで質問するのはアリですか？

Tags: 討議, サポート

英語版 Stack Overflow の分からないことを日本語版スタック・オーバーフローメタで質問するのはアリですか？

英語版で質問したものの、ついたコメントの意味が良く分からず、英語で応対も難しくなったときに、この日本語版のメタで日本語で聞くのはアリですか？

Answer (score 6):

自分の考えを回答として投稿しておきます（もちろん他の回答も歓迎です！）。

まず、英語版 Stack Overflow に関する質問を日本語版のメタに投稿するのは、日本語版メタの質問の範囲を超えています。日本語版メタは日本語版スタック・オーバーフローに関する質問を投稿する場所であり、英語版のための場所ではありません。

[「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

> スタック・オーバーフローのメタとは、プログラミングについての議論ではなく、スタック・オーバーフロー自体の使い方や方針についてユーザーが議論するための場所です。

名前は似ていても Stack Overflow とスタック・オーバーフローでは文化が異なり、この意味でも日本語版メタでは対応しきれない場合があります。

このため、もし英語版に関する質問が投稿された場合はクローズ投票するのが妥当だと考えています。

一方で、ただ無碍にクローズしてしまうのも日本語を使うプログラマーのためになっておらず、スタック・オーバーフローの本懐を果たせていないのではないか、とも思います。英語で大丈夫そうなら英語版メタに誘導したり、日本語でサポートが必要そうならコメントから[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)へ誘導してそちらで話すなど、状況に応じて対応するのがより be nice そうです。