# AskQuestion。英語でYou have reached your question limitでます。質問する。日本語で、でません。

Tags: サポート

英語と、日本語で異なりますか?
日本語でも、でる事がありますか?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/8059863/mrrclb48z
上記で下記のように、書かれています。
「
Congratulations!
Thanks to your efforts, you earned
● Autobiographer
」

Comment: ご質問の意味がよく分かりませんでした。スクリーンショットを含めるなどして、具体的に何にお困りなのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。何かしたいことができない、などでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 前置き

[過去にも同様の指摘を受けている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3326) かと思いますが、利用にあたっての疑問等はサイト毎に用意されているメタにおいて質問を投稿してください。

サポートを行うモデレーターについても各サイトごとにメンバーが違います。私を含め日本語版におけるモデレーターも英語版では単なる一ユーザーに過ぎないので、十分なフォローが出来ない可能性が高いです。

また、投稿にあたって質問のタイトルや本文は読み手に対して伝わる文章を心がけてください。
申し訳ないですが過去の投稿も第三者が読んだときに意図が読み取りづらい内容のものが多い印象です。

---

#### 質問への回答

"You have reached your question limit" のメッセージについては、あなたの過去の投稿がコミュニティから低品質とみなされて一時的に新規投稿を受け付けない状態になった場合に表示されるものです。

- [Stack Overflow - 'you have reached your question limit'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273741)
- [私のアカウントからの質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？ - ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

あくまで停止は一時的なものですが、上記リンク先を参考にまずは過去の投稿内容を改善する事から始めてみてください。

なお、追記された "Autobiographer" については、信用度に応じて得られる [バッジの説明](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer) ですので、元々の質問とは無関係なものです。